# If I have many distributable packages in the same repository, do I need to include a LICENSE file with all of them?

Tags: license

I'm creating a project with Lerna, so there's multiple NPM packages in the same repository.

Is it necessary for me to place a LICENSE file inside each NPM package, such that when the user downloads the package they can read the license, or is it enough to place a LICENSE file in the root of the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, each package should have a license. That way they can be used individually.

NPM is weird though in that it lends it's self to "micro-packages" very well. So it's quite possible that your licensing documentation exceeds the size of your package.

In short, if your packages come from the outside then they should already have a license that you should respect. If they are internal only, then each package should have its own license.